# Unable to playback special events using journal playback

Tags: windows, visual-c++, remote-desktop, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to simulate a remote control software. So, I have used journalrecord global hook to capture all the events from machine1. The captured events are transferred via data channel to the machine2. At the receiving side, I collect the events to buffer and start playing with journalplayback hook. In that process I'm unable to play windows key, windows+r, alt-tab key combinations. I see that my sent and received events are same with out loss.

My logic for the record and playback message times are:

At Record side, I modify the eventmsg structure time as,

> Record_EventMsg->time = timeGetTime();

at playback side, the delta computation is.

> delay = (playback_msg_.time - playback_first_msg_time_) -
>                (timeGetTime() - playback_start_time_);
>
> if (delay < 0)
>     delay = 0;
>
> return delay;